# Xcode test iphone 6?

Tags: xcode

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I couldn't find any answer on Google.

Is there a way now to test apps on the `iPhone 6` , with `Xcode` ?

Checking on the `App Store`, i can only see `version 5.1.1` of `Xcode`, and on the dev site there is the `Xcode 6 GM seed`

So what does `Xcode 6 GM seed` means ? is it *stable* version? Do we need it to test our app with the new `iPhones 6` or there is another way to do that with the current `Xcode`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the same thing!  This is what the organizer shows:

The version of iOS on “CJ’s iPhone 6” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on CJ’s iPhone 6
8.0 (12A365)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions

Answer (score 0):

Download Xcode 6.0.1 and you'll see iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus in the simulator.